# Simulating RSSI with Cheap RF Modules

Tags: arduino, radio-transmission

My goal is to essentially spoof RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indicator) using a system of counting received packets. The idea is to have something where:

- A specific number of packets is sent in a specific time from the transmitter.
- Then are received at another unit and the number of packets received is counted.
- The number in the counter of the receiver indicates the number of packets received at that time specific in the transmitter.
- The fewer packages (counter value) that are received, the farther the sender will be.

I'm having a little trouble implementing the logic in my code however so I'd really appreciate the help. I am using Arduino Pro Mini 5V with NRF24L01+ radios and the RF24 Network library. My code is as follows:

Transmitter:

```cpp
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

RF24 radio(8,9);                    

RF24Network network(radio);         

const uint16_t home_node = 00;   
const uint16_t distant_node = 01;   

struct payload_t {                  // Structure of our payload
  byte ID;
};


void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  network.begin(/*channel*/ 92, /*node address*/ distant_node);
}

void loop(void) {

  byte ID = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    payload_t payload = {ID};                           
    RF24NetworkHeader header(/*to node*/ home_node);
    bool ok = network.write(header,&payload,sizeof(payload));
    if (ok)
      Serial.println("ok.");
    else
      Serial.println("failed.");
    delay (300); 
  }
  delay(15000);
}
```

Receiver:

```cpp
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

RF24 radio(8,9);                    

RF24Network network(radio);         

const uint16_t home_node = 00;   
const uint16_t distant_node = 01;

struct payload_t {
  byte ID;
};

//const unsigned long interval = 3000; 
//unsigned long last_sent;
int count = 0;


void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  network.begin(/*channel*/ 92, /*node address*/ home_node);
}

void loop(void)
{
  RF24NetworkHeader header;
  payload_t payload;
  network.update();
  while ( network.available() ) {     // Is there anything ready for us?
     bool ok = network.read(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));
     if (ok) // Non-blocking
     {
       count++;
       Serial.println ("count=");
       Serial.println (count);
     }
     else 
       Serial.println ("Failed");

  }
}
```

Comment: To be precise, what you will get is an LQI (link quality indicator) rather than RSSI but the two are more or less related to each other. Could you precise your question ,what is not working as expected in the code ?

Comment: @Julien The goal is to take that pseudo-RSSI or LQI as you pointed it out and take a ton of data points to approximate the distance. The problem in the code is that I always get 50 packets sent across no matte what distance the other receiver is at, so I think I need to impose some sort of time limit so that not all the packets have a chance to get across.

Comment: You can either add a timeout (send 10 frames/seconds, how many frames did I get in last 10 seconds ? or easier to implement : how many time since last frame I got and calculate the number of lost frames) OR put a counter into your radio packets (how many frames do I lose between two packets I receive ?)